# I'm trying to write a loop that raises the mathematical constant of pi to its powers until the result is greater than 10000

Tags: python

```
 math.pi = 3.14
 while math.pi > 10000
     print math.pi
```

I'm trying to write a loop that raises the mathematical constant of pi to its powers until the result is greater than 10000

Comment: It's unlikely that `math.pi > 10,000` will ever be true.

Comment: You should start with a variable equals to math.pi as your starting point. Then raise that var to the different powers inside a loop till it the variable's equal to 10,000 or more.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Have you forgot to change the value of pi? Because currently your code will never enter the while loop because math.pi is a constant and math.pi < 10000.

Comment: @XavierC. except that it will never print anything

Comment: @Dartmouth. Edit, thanks :)

Comment: what do  you mean _its powers_?

Comment: `math.pi = 3.14` oh Lord  `I came to where ?` You don't need `PI` you already declared it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? I tried to provide an example with as similar format to what you provided.

```
import math

exponent = 0
num = math.pi

while num ** exponent < 10000:
    print num ** exponent
    exponent += 1
```

If we take a look at the code that you posted, you're never changing the value of pi. The loop will never start, because the value of pi will never be greater than 10,000. Also, your condition should be `while num ** exponent < 10000:` because you want the while loop to execute while the result is less than 10,000. When the value is greater than 10,000, the loop will stop and no longer execute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to actually assign pi to a variable and increase it's value

```
p = math.pi
while p < 10000: 
    p *= math.pi
```

or using a bit of math you can get the same result:

```
p = math.pi ** (math.ceil(math.log(10000) / math.log(math.pi)))
```

Comment: Dang it! Beat my just a few seconds.

Comment: actually realised that will not actually return the result, edited to fix